# JavaScript in ASP behaving different in IE as to FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, firefox

I have an ASP page where the JavaScript behaves differently in IE10 (correctly) than it does in FireFox (latest version).

I have a random color generator as follows:

```
// Function to generate random colours
function rgbcolors() {
  // rgb string generation
  var col = "rgb("
  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ","
  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ","
  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")";
  //change the text color with the new random color
  return col;
}
```

I then use a variable to store the random color:

```
var strColor = rgbcolors();
```

Now, when I use that color variable else where it seems to regenerate a random color in FireFox and not the one stored in the variable:

```
strHTML += '<td align="center"><font color="' + strColor + '">'
```

Then here the color is different:

```
var pieData = [
  {
    value: intUsed,
    color: strColor
  },
```

Strangely IE10 works 100% as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) for the `<font>` tag, you have these issues:

1. `<font>` was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and obsoleted in HTML 5 (though browsers will retain varying forms of support for it).  But, there is ZERO reason to write new code that uses it.
2. The color attribute takes a named color or one in the #RRGGBB format.  The rgb(x,y,z) format is not mentioned as being supported for the `<font color=xxx>` attribute.

I'd suggest you start using `style.color` instead.

---

Also, keep in mind that when you have a data structure like this:

```
var pieData = [
  {
    value: intUsed,
    color: strColor
  }
```

This is going to capture the then current value of the `strColor` string variable.  If you subsequently change the value of `strColor`, your pieData data structure will still have the old value of `strColor` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will try use the style='color:... attribute instead and research how to convert decimal to hex for JavaScript.  I actually know very little about JavaScript.

Comment: @user3017424 - you can use the `rgb()` format with `style.color`.

Comment: I used the #000000 format and now it is working in both IE and FireFox.  I found a small function to convert to hex.  I am fairly good with VBScript but JavaScript is another beast altogether.